# pthreads producer-consumer deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock, producer-consumer

I wrote following code:

```
void *produce(void* arg)
{
 buffer* buff = (buffer *) arg;
 while (1)
 {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  if (elements_produced == JOB_SIZE)
  {
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
  elements_produced++;

  while (buff->in_buff == CAPACITY)
  {
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond_empty, &mutex);
  }

  // produce
  buff->buffer[buff->tail] = rand();
  sum_produced += buff->buffer[buff->tail];
  printf(">produced %d\n", buff->buffer[buff->tail]);

  buff->tail = (buff->tail + 1) % CAPACITY;
  buff->in_buff++;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_empty);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *consume(void* arg)
{
 int rc;
 buffer* buff = (buffer *) arg;
 while (1)
 { 
  rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  if (elements_consumed == JOB_SIZE)
  {
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
  }
  elements_consumed++;

  while (buff->in_buff == 0)
  {   
   rc = pthread_cond_wait(&cond_empty, &mutex);
  }

  // consume  
  printf("<consumed %d\n", buff->buffer[buff->head]);
  sum_consumed += buff->buffer[buff->head];
  buff->head = (buff->head + 1) % CAPACITY;
  buff->in_buff--;
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond_full);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
 return 0;
}
```

All variables are properly initialized. The task is to produce JOB_SIZE elements and to consume them. From time to time it gets stuck in the dead lock. I am quite new to the posix threads so I am probably missing something very obvious (did producers/consumers many times in java/C#/python but now I am really stuck). I know it is much easier to do it with semaphores but I need to do it in this way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many condvars are involved? Should the producer be waiting on `cond_full` rather than `cond_empty`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used cond_empty in both sides for the wait.  You signal (but never wait on) cond_full.

Comment: Waiting on `cond_empty` in both cases should work, but you need to ensure that you signal it in both cases too.

Comment: I feel kind of embarrassed after this. I don't know how I hadn't seen this. Tnx.

Comment: @Anthony Williams: That's what I thought he was doing at first, so I almost didn't catch the other condition.